# Drupal menu_block item is rendering twice

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a site on Drupal 7 and a template file for a content type is printing my menu twice. A module named menu_block is installed on the site.

My menu is rendered by this call:

```
<?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>
```

Even if I clear the code entirely I can see on text my menu options twice and on the HTML code a class is added to the first one "menu-block-1" and the second one "menu-block-2".

Answer (score 0):

So, if they have different machine names that means that you have 2 different blocks displaying same menu. Check out Structure -> Blocks to see what block are placed at `side_first` region. Also check for some other modules that can add block to region. Maybe blocks are added different way. Do you have i.e. "Context" module installed?

Comment: Hi Milan, Thanks for your repply. I found that one menu have a display condition and it calls a function like this: menu_link_get_preferred(NULL, 'menu-left-nav'); that it used to return the right value but it looks like after an update it always return false.

Comment: Hmm...never used that one. But check out, maybe with update that function also changed. Maybe it takes different parameters.